# Get Dialog Size as defined in resource file

Tags: windows, api, dialog

I need to determine the size of a dialog client area as defined in the resource file.

GetClientRect clips the design size by the size of the desktop.  I need the size as designed in screen units.  I found [this](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-d/dislog/miscellaneous/article.php/c5005) which purports to retrieve the size form the dialog resource but sadly it uses MFC.

I have the dialog open and have its HWND and it's ID.  How can I get the dsign size in screen units without using MFC stuff?

Comment: The code you linked does the equivalent of calling CreateDialog with the dialog's resource ID, and then calling GetClientRect. You will probably have to resort to actually parsing the template in the resources.

Comment: @pezcode: So I use FindResource, LoadResource and LockResource to get a pointer to the dialog resource starting with a DLGTEMPLATE and from there I get cx and cy or the size in dialog box units.  Then use GetDialogBaseUnits to convert to screen units? Does the resource remain locked for the life of process?  Should I avoid locking it multiple times?

Comment: Classic XY question.  Suppose you find out, what exactly are you going to do with that information?

Comment: @HansPassant: I have some dialogs larger than the standard 800x600 which do not display properly on small screens.  I've added scroll bars but need the design sizes in order to operate the scroll bars properly.  I have this more or less working but have some problems translating from dialog base units to screen units.

Comment: Sounds like the problem I am having. But I can’t compile your accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SIZE GetDialogSize(INT nResourceId, BOOL bApproximateCalcMethod = FALSE, LPCTSTR strDllName = NULL)
{

    SIZE dlgSize = {0}; 
    HINSTANCE hModule = 0;

    if(strDllName != NULL)   
        hModule= ::LoadLibrary(strDllName);              
    else
        hModule = ::GetModuleHandle(NULL);   

    HRSRC hRsrc = ::FindResource(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(nResourceId), RT_DIALOG);  

    HGLOBAL hTemplate = ::LoadResource(hModule, hRsrc);  

    DLGTEMPLATE* pTemplate = (DLGTEMPLATE*)::LockResource(hTemplate);

    if (bApproximateCalcMethod) // the approximate method of calculating
    {
        LONG dlgBaseUnits = GetDialogBaseUnits();
        int baseunitX = LOWORD(dlgBaseUnits), baseunitY = HIWORD(dlgBaseUnits);
        dlgSize.cx = MulDiv(pTemplate->cx, baseunitX, 4);
        dlgSize.cy = MulDiv(pTemplate->cy, baseunitY, 8);
    }
    else // the accurate method of calculation
    {
        HWND hDlg = ::CreateDialogIndirect(0, pTemplate, NULL, DialogProc);         
        RECT rc = {0};
        ::GetWindowRect(hDlg, &rc);
        ::DestroyWindow(hDlg);

        dlgSize.cx = rc.right - rc.left;
        dlgSize.cy = rc.bottom - rc.top;
    }

    UnlockResource(hTemplate);
    ::FreeResource(hTemplate);

    if(strDllName != NULL)
        ::FreeLibrary(hModule);

    return dlgSize;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had more or less doped this out using pezcode's hints but the translation from dialog units to screen units is a still problem and the cleanup code is very useful.  Won't your accurate method return the clipped size if the dialog is bigger than the desktop?

Comment: I've had very good results using MapDialogRect to convert from Dialog units to screen units.

Comment: The MapDialogRect works perfectly for me in translating dialog units to screen units.  In my case, I had the dialog HWND so that was straight forward.  In hellkni9ht's code that could be substituted for the GetWindowRect in "the accurate method of calculation".

Comment: DLGTEMPLATE Is coming up as undefined for me. Why?