# How to get the size and position of a button control of a dialog in a resource file?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to programmatically design a dialog menu that resizes based on the resolution of the screen, and I am able to get the size and positions of the dialog using the dialog's `nameID` following this question:

[Get Dialog Size as defined in resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458555/get-dialog-size-as-defined-in-resource-file/9458692)

However, I'm having trouble trying to obtain the size and positions of the button controls within the dialog. Here's an example of what the dialog might look like in the resource file:

```
IDD_DLG DIALOG  0, 0, 300, 200
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,30,46,42,18
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,145,46,42,18
END
```

I can obtain the dialog's size and positions using its `nameID`, i.e. `IDD_DLG`, but is it possible to obtain the same thing for the `DEFPUSHBUTTON` or `PUSHBUTTON` programmatically?

If so, how? Thanks!

Comment: If you are trying to design dialog menu programmatically then there is no point in using resource scripts...

Comment: @VTT agreed but unfortunately there are requirements for me to use the resource file as the foundation to design the menus programmatically

Comment: Since you already know, how to retrieve a [`DLGTEMPLATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/ns-winuser-dlgtemplate), it should be obvious how to proceed: *"\[The `DLGTEMPLATE`\] structure, always the first in a standard template for a dialog box, also specifies the number of controls in the dialog box and therefore specifies the number of subsequent [`DLGITEMTEMPLATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-dlgitemtemplate) structures in the template."* The documentation describes the precise layout of items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MFC allows automatic repositioning/resizing of child buttons. In resource property page, click on dialog button, go to dynamic control section, enable dynamic resizing/move for each button.

To find the coordinates of the button, relative to top-left of dialog client window:

Use `GetWindowRect` to find the buttons rectangle in screen coordinates. Then convert the screen coordinates to client coordinates:

```
CMyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    CRect rc;
    CWnd *wnd = GetDlgItem(IDOK);
    wnd->GetWindowRect(&rc);
    ScreenToClient(rc);
    ...
    //move/resize rc
    wnd->SetWindowPos(NULL, rc.left, rc.top, rc.Width(), rc.Height(), SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
}
```

Comment: the method SetWindowRect is not available in CWnd class, please check